# Stream read/write error on 64-bit application

Tags: delphi, winapi

I read my physical drive and am having some problems.

**64-bit applications:**

- 512 bytes: `Stream read error`/`Stream write error`.

  - `Read`: work
  - `ReadBuffer`: not work
- 38400 bytes: work.

**32-bit applications:** work on all cases.

```
function setinact(diskid: string): boolean;
var
  hdevi:    THandleStream;
  hDevice:  THandle;
  mfile:    TMemoryStream;
  hbuff, mbuff:    array[0..511] of byte;
  i:        integer;
  BytesReturned: DWORD;
begin
  Result:=False;
  hDevice := CreateFile(Pchar('\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE'+diskid), GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  if hDevice <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    try
      hdevi := THandleStream.Create(hDevice);
      try
        mfile:=TMemoryStream.Create();
        try
          hdevi.ReadBuffer(hbuff[0],length(hbuff));
          mfile.WriteBuffer(hbuff[0],Length(hbuff));
          mfile.Position:=0;
          mfile.ReadBuffer(mbuff[0],length(mbuff));
          mbuff[446]:=$00;
          mbuff[462]:=$00;
          mbuff[478]:=$00;
          mbuff[494]:=$00;
          hdevi.Position:=0;
          hdevi.WriteBuffer(mbuff[0],length(mbuff));
          Result:=True;
        finally
          mfile.Free;
        end;
      finally
        hdevi.Free;
        DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_PROPERTIES, nil, 0, nil, 0, BytesReturned, nil);
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hDevice);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

How to read 512 bytes on 64-bit applications?

**Updated:**
I've run this application on another PC, it worked. I do not understand why.

**Updated 2:**
Thanks to David Heffernan. The code below work. But why for 32-bit applications, it always succeed with the first code?

```
function setinact(diskid: string): boolean;
var
  hDevice:  THandle;
  hbuff:    PByte;
  i:        integer;
  hexstr: String;
  DISK_GEOMETRY : _DISK_GEOMETRY;
  BytesPerSector: Int64;
  BytesReturned: DWORD;
begin
  Result:=False;
  hDevice := CreateFile(Pchar('\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE'+diskid), GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  if hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then Exit;
  try
    GetMem(hbuff, 512);
    try
      if not DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, Nil, 0, @DISK_GEOMETRY, sizeof(DISK_GEOMETRY), BytesReturned, nil) then Exit;
      BytesPerSector:=DISK_GEOMETRY.BytesPerSector;
      if not ReadFile(hDevice, hbuff^, 512, BytesReturned, nil) then Exit;

      .................

      SetFilePointer(hDevice, 0, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
      if not WriteFile(hDevice, hbuff^, 512, BytesReturned, nil) then Exit;
    finally
      FreeMem(hbuff, 512);
    end;
    Result:=True;
    DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_PROPERTIES, nil, 0, nil, 0, BytesReturned, nil);
  finally
    CloseHandle(hDevice);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: @Vinícius This line `hdevi.ReadBuffer(hbuff[0],length(hbuff));`

Comment: As David says: it may work on some computers but not on others, or even on Win32 on the same system but not on Win64, depending on the drivers and the hard disk used. So if it works on your computer(s) it may still fail on others. Your updated code is still not correct. It may work for you, but not for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950(v=vs.85).aspx) you need to ensure that the memory that you read in to is sector aligned.

> File access buffer addresses for read and write operations should be physical sector-aligned, which means aligned on addresses in memory that are integer multiples of the volume's physical sector size. Depending on the disk, this requirement may not be enforced.

Allocate two sectors worth of memory and then advance within that to a sector boundary.

```
var
  buff: array [0..2*512-1] of Byte;
  ptr: Pointer;
.... 
ptr := Pointer((NativeInt(@buff) + 512) and not (512-1));
```

After this, `ptr` points to an aligned location within your over-sized buffer. Perform your direct disk access with the memory starting at this aligned location.

The final sentence of the excerpt explains that this requirement may not be enforced which is why your code may work on some machines but not others.

Or indeed you may just be lucky with your 32 bit builds that they happen to give you a sector aligned memory address. Your supposed fix in the question edit doesn't help since `GetMem` has no 512 byte alignment guarantee. If a call to `GetMem` happens to return an address that is 512 byte aligned, that's just chance. You cannot rely on that.

```
        S                             S 
  B     |                             |
  +---------------------------------------------------------+
  |     ******************************                      |
  +---------------------------------------------------------+
        P                             |

S: sector boundary (multiple of 512) 
B: buffer (2*512 bytes in size!), not aligned to sector boundary
P: Ptr = buffer + offset to make ptr aligned to a sector boundary.
*: part of buffer you use (512 bytes), aligned to sector boundary
```

---

There seems to be some confusion, judging from the comments. Let me see if I can spell this out a little more. Two aspects of direct disk access need to be aligned.

1. The disk pointer and block size must be sector aligned.
2. The memory buffer must be sector aligned.

I am referring to the second of these. You are meeting the first requirement, assuming the disk sector size is 512. But you are failing to meet the second requirement.

Comment: But this work when running 32-bit application. I've run this application on another System, it worked. I do not understand why. `BytesPerSector` of my disk is 512 bytes.

Comment: *Depending on the disk, this requirement may not be enforced.*

Comment: In other words you are violating a requirement that it is stated may or not be enforced. On the machines where it is not enforced your code runs correctly. On machines where it is enforced it fails.

Comment: Thanks! I have used the value of `BytesPerSector` from `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY` but it also did not work. Perhaps I'm using the system were not working properly.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand. It's not the number of bytes you are reading. It's the address of the memory into which you read that I refer to.

Comment: I just use a USB for both systems. I also think I'm not understand.

Comment: 512 aligned disk access is fine. It's the address of the *memory* which you read and write from and to that matters also.

Comment: What @David is saying is that the **address** of the buffer can not be something like `$12345684`, it must be something like `$12345800`, i.e. it must be on a 512 byte *boundary* in memory. You can achieve that by allocating a larger buffer and adjusting the *address* of a pointer to that buffer to be aligned to 512 byte. In other words, if you have a pointer that has the value `$12345684`, his code turns it into a pointer with value `$12345800`, which points to somewhere in that (large) buffer, and uses the 512 bytes at that address as the buffer for the call.

Comment: Thank all, I have updated my question. Why for 32-bit applications, it always succeed with the first code?

Comment: We've been round this so many times. *Depending on the disk, this requirement may not be enforced.* I think that's pretty clear, no? Also your updated code won't work because `GetMem` doesn't give you 512 byte alignment.

Comment: But `GetMem` worked for me, I have scored data to the USB without any errors.

Comment: So you were lucky. Well, actually unlucky in the sense that you now think that you have solved the problem when in fact you have not. You have to realise that just because something works once does not mean that it works every time. Ask the next person you meet whether they are right handed or left handed. Can you take the answer they give and infer that all people are that way?

Comment: @Whoami: so you were lucky it worked on that one particular system, either because GetMem returned, by chance, an address that had the desired value, or because the disk driver on that system did not have the sector size requirement. But on oher systems, it can still fail if you don't follow David's advice and use his code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: I don't know how to use data types that you have mentioned. In documents say `One way to sector-align buffers is to use the [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx](VirtualAlloc) function to allocate the buffers.` Is it ok to use? I'm not sure about "some" but my product has been widely used in more than half a year. I just try the 64-bit version today.

Comment: You can use `VirtualAlloc` but it's much easier my way. Do you know about pointers?

Comment: I don't know :(

Comment: Do you understand what the code in my answer is attempting to do? Do you understand what we mean by an address aligned on a 512 byte boundary?

Comment: I think you are allocated memory is a multiple of 512? I have suggested that it should be applied only if the amount is more than one sector.

Comment: That makes no sense to me.

Comment: I do not understand about the address, number of bytes to read and position.

Comment: The address in memory must have a numeric value that is a multiple of the sector size. An address of 512 is good. An address of 511 or 513 is not. 2*512 is OK, 3*512 also. etc. The number of bytes that you read must be a multiple of the sector size, 512, 2*512, 3*512 etc.

Comment: Well, this is new for me. I have read the values in pointer, but it seems it does not coincide with the HEX code?

Comment: Nevemind. I can't devote any more of my time to this. Try and work it out yourself with some independent research.

Comment: @David: How to determine the position of 512 bytes in 1024 bytes of `buff`?I've been using the `Move` function to declare a new variable, `Move(ptr^, newbuff[0], 512);` Worked!

Comment: You can read directly from ptr^ into your memory stream. `mfile.WriteBuffer(ptr^, 512)`

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. Thanks!